# How to get Node.js console output to my website

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js running in my command prompt on Windows. Now what I like to do is somehow echo the console info as html on a webpage. How do i manage this? And if so how do i pass arguments?

Thanks and correct me if I have the wrong idea..

EDIT:

This is how i generate my output:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.2
(function() {
     var LolClient, client, options, summoner, util;

  LolClient = require('./lol-client');

  util = require('util');

  options = {
    region: '',
    username: '',
    password: '',
    version: '3.6.16_05_29_18_19'
  };

  summoner = {
    name: 'HotshotGG',
    acctId: 434582,
    summonerId: 407750,
    teamId: "TEAM-a1ebba15-986f-488a-ae2f-e081b2886ba4"
  };

  client = new LolClient(options);

  client.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.getSummonerByName(summoner.name, function(err, result) {
      return console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null, true));
    });
    client.getSummonerStats(summoner.acctId, function(err, result) {
      return console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null, true));
    });
    client.getMatchHistory(summoner.acctId, function(err, result) {
      return console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null, true));
    });
    client.getAggregatedStats(summoner.acctId, function(err, result) {
      return console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null, true));
    });
    client.getTeamsForSummoner(summoner.summonerId, function(err, result) {
      return console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null, true));
    });
    client.getTeamById(summoner.teamId, function(err, result) {
      return console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null, true));
    });
    return client.getSummonerData(summoner.acctId, function(err, result) {
      return console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null, true));
    });
  });

  client.connect();

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Do you want your console output piped to browser or do you really want to create webpages with node.js?

Comment: A webpage. So that i can read it with a PHP crawler... The app i have is an API platform which I want to access on my PHP site.

Comment: Then you should try a node.js webframe work. Express might be a good choice (http://expressjs.com/)

Comment: AH thanks, ehm... How would i echo this as text on a webpage in Express I tried it out and I am quite confused...

Answer (score 2):

You could try this if you want a somewhat full-featured solution: https://npmjs.org/package/node-monkey

For something simpler, you could just redirect the output of your node instance on the server to a file, while also enabling static serving of that file via the node server itself.  Say, using Express to serve a single static file, which is easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried out Node-monkey. Do you happen to know more about this because I ran into a problem...

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't used it myself.  I suppose you can post a new question with your new issue.